# Roslyn with .NET core on linux: How can I load an external project?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, code-generation, roslyn

First of all, I don't know much about Roslyn. I went through a few tutorials hot to generate code and how to parse a string containing code.
So far, everything is clear to me.

Here is my question:
I'm using dotnet core 1.0.1 on Linux.
I created a new project with some interfaces defining some properties. 
What I want to do is to create a program in which I can load the project, run trough the interfaces (*.cs files) and generate some code.
My problem is, I don't know how to load/open a c# project with Roslyn.

The tutorials I found are using a windows environment. These samples doesn't work on my environment because there are some dependencies to MSBuild or Visual Studio. I read and tried some things about the AdhocWorkspace, but I didn't manage to open an existing solution this way.

Can anyone give me a hint how to start?
Is it possible to open/load a project (*.csproj) and run through all *.cs-files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no good way to open .Net projects using Roslyn on .Net Core.

See [this issue on the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17968), where the recommended solution is to use code from the Omnisharp project.

Comment: I tried it now by copying some classes from Omnisharp DotNetWorkspace which lead my to the next problem, that it uses functionalities from Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel, which are still working with the project.json file, instead of the csproj. At least in the current version I got from Nuget.org.
But, nevertheless, I got a picture how it may be solved, by looking through Omnisharp's solution.

So thank you very much for the hint.